# Error creating universal windows app in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, win-universal-app

Whenever I try to create a blank universal app template under C#, I get the following error:

> Error Reading JToken From JSONReader. Path ", line 1, position 267.

This results in a failed project creation, and if I try to build the solution I get approximately 200 errors.

[image: These were the errors while building the solution.]

I have tried saving the project and then building it.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Also, is this one of the beta project types?

Comment: My guess is that the app template is  corrupted.  Suggest repairing or reinstalling VS.

Comment: This VS2015 bug has bitten me many times already.  One of the many bugs in the RTM version, Microsoft's new focus on agile development has only created features but not stable code or a quick update release schedule.  You must turn on the Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > "Save new projects when created" checkbox before you create a Universal project.  The default setting, apparently you turned it off.

Comment: I have tried Reinstalling the whole visual studio but it didn't worked. and also "Save new projects when created" was checked by default. please suggest any other solution